# Wrong results with tensorflow prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, prediction, image-classification

I have trained a simple CNN for binary image-classification. Then I tried to make predictions. I used ImageDataGenerator to create a prediction-iterator (predict_it). Then I used

```
probabilities = model.predict(predict_it)
```

and got the following results, which are plausible:

```
print(probabilities)
 [[9.0815449e-01]
 [1.9250402e-02]
 [9.8504424e-01]
 ...
 [4.3504283e-06]
 [3.5914429e-06]
 [7.5442227e-07]]
```

So the model itself seems to work correctly. However, this method of prediction processes an entire subdirectory filled with images. Therefore I tried to process a single image. But then I **always get the same value** when executing the following code (multiple times for 8 different images):

```
probabilitiy = model.predict(single_image)
```

Result:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 82ms/step
probability: [[0.5078959]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step
probability: [[0.5078958]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step
probability: [[0.5078958]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step
probability: [[0.5078958]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step
probability: [[0.50789577]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step
probability: [[0.5078958]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step
probability: [[0.5078957]]
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step
probability: [[0.5078958]]
```

Does anyone have an idea how this can happen?

Thanks in advance.

I tried to save the model in different forms: (.keras and .h5) - but that didn't change the results mentioned above.

The code I use to preprocess a single image:

```
# a function to load and prepare each image
def load_image(filename):
    # load the image
    img = load_img(filename, grayscale=False, target_size=(256, 256))
    # convert to array
    img = img_to_array(img)
    # reshape into a single sample with 1 channel
    img = img.reshape(1, 256, 256, 3)
    # prepare pixel data
    img = img.astype("float32")
    img = img / 255.0
    return img    


# run through all files in a specified folder
for filename in files:
    # load a single image
    img = load_image(filename)
    # predict the probability
    probability = model.predict(img)  
    # display the result
    print(f"probability: {probability}")
```

Comment: How did you preprocess the images? Maybe the problem is in the code that is used to open and preprocess the images.

Comment: Did you try other image? Are you getting different probabilities for different kinds of input images?

Comment: Yes, as written, I tried 8 different images (4 for each class) and the results are always the same.

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin: I edited my question and added the code I used to preprocess a single image. Perhaps you can check this... thanks

Comment: Did you divide the image arrays by 255.0 when training?

Comment: Yes, I added a Rescaling layer to the model right in the beginning: ```x = layers.Rescaling(1./255)(inputs)```

Comment: Can you please share the whole working code snippets? It would be very hard for the community to debug only based on the function.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution in the Keras documentation on the rescaling layer:
"Rescaling is applied both during training and inference."

Since my model has a rescaling-layer I must pass an image to the model (when doing single image prediction) which is NOT rescaled already. Otherwise rescaling is applied twice!

So the correct code for preprocessing a single image for prediction is:

````
def load_image(filename):
    # load the image
    img = load_img(filename, grayscale=False, target_size=(256, 256))
    # convert to array
    img = img_to_array(img)
    # reshape into a single sample with 1 channel
    img = img.reshape(1, 256, 256, 3)
    # prepare pixel data
    img = img.astype("float32")
    return img    


# run through all files in a specified folder
for filename in files:
    # load a single image
    img = load_image(filename)
    # predict the probability
    probability = model.predict(img)  
    # display the result
    print(f"probability: {probability}")```
````